# PyNUFFT. Function defined over regular grid?

Tags: python, fft

I want to perform the 3D NonUniformFFT of a scalar field defined over the points of a crystal with complex geometry and I found [PyNUFFT](http://jyhmiinlin.github.io/pynufft/index.html#document-API/init).

Now I don't understand the process (1D). They define a set of **M** non-unif. distributed *(x-)* points `om` which shall be fourier transformed. On the other side its **N_d** *(y-)* time-series values are uniformly distributed and there is a different amount.

[image]

Does this mean I always need this kind of extrapolated description of the y(x) function I want to transform, defined over a regular grid? In my problem of the crystal I only have my x/om positions with their respective function value y(x).

Also this om values in the example barely range from [-3,3], so I dont get quite how it is able to describe the time-series properly.

Any tips are welcome!

Nothing to try, I have problem understanding the concept.